# How to wait for function with subscribe to finish in angular 8?

Tags: async-await, observable, angular8, wait, subscribe

I want to wait for one function to finish before executing the function next to it.
I have one function called **getData()** in which http call occurs which returns an observable. The second function **checkDuplicate()** we have subscribed to that function **getData()** . and we have third function called **proceed()** in which we call the **checkDuplicate()** function and once the **checkDuplicate()** function is completed, we are calling **alert("finished")**. But the issue here is even before **checkDuplicate()** function is completed, alert has been triggered.

find the code for better clarification:

```
getData(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get<any>(URL...);
}

checkDuplicate(){

return this.getData().subscribe(response => {
   if(response){
      console.log("Inside");
  }
});
}

proceed(){
 this.checkDuplicate();
 console.log("finished");
}
```

**Actual Result**

finished

Inside

**Expected result**

Inside

finished

I have tried **asyn/await** to wait for checkDuplicate() function to finish. But still no use.
It would be grateful if u share the solution.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 8):

The gotcha of async programming. Here's a solution with promises (you can also use observables):

```
getData(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get<any>(URL...);
}

async checkDuplicate(){
  var response = await this.getData().toPromise();
  if (response) {
      console.log("Inside");
  }
}

async proceed(){
 await this.checkDuplicate();
 console.log("finished");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer @Andrei Tătar !! But still am getting the same issue

Comment: @sherinshaf you're probably using different code. Post your complete code.

Comment: Same code. As soon as i call ```await this.getData().toPromise();``` control goes to console.log("finished") in proceed() function.. its not waiting for response

Comment: have you copied all the code from my response? `proceed` also has async/await

Comment: What about in we are in an interceptor that it is not async method?

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido http interceptors can return an Observable or a Promise so they are asynchronous. You can use Promises (async/await) together with Observables...

Answer (score 1):

Lost a lot of time on this one. You have to use `lastValueFrom` as specified here: [Conversion to Promises](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise). `ToPromise()` has been deprecated.

```
import { lastValueFrom, tap } from 'rxjs';

getData(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get<any>(URL...);
}

async checkDuplicate(){
  return await lastValueFrom(this.getData()
    .pipe(tap(response => {
      if(response){
        console.log("Inside");
      }
    })
  ));
}

async proceed(){
  await this.checkDuplicate();
  console.log("finished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update something like this.

```
getData(): Observable<any>{
return this.http.get<any>(URL...);
}


checkDuplicate() {
return Promise(resolve=>{
this.getData().subscribe(response => {
if(response){
console.log("Inside");
 }
resolve(true);
});
});
}


proceed(){
this.checkDuplicate().then(value=>{
console.log("Return from promise => "+ value);
console.log("finished");
});
}
```

You can return promise from checkDuplicate and call another function after it is resolved by using "then".